# PHP while loop that increases by a variable amount each cycle

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, do-while

Good afternoon, as a homework I've been doing the same program with different structures, the goal of this one is that the user inputs 3 different values (starting point, finishing number and the increasing number).

This is how it worked using the for structure:

```
$varP=0;
$varIncA=$_POST['varIncA'];
$varFinA=$_POST['varFinA'];
$varIniA=$_POST['varIniA'];

if($varFinA - $varIniA <= $varIncA){
echo "Dude, there is something really messed up with your reasoning process, please try again with an increasing value smaller than the difference between the first value and the final one.";
}
else {
    for($varP=$varIniA; $varP<=$varFinA; $varP=$varP+$varIncA){
        echo $varP . ".-hello" . "<br>";    
    }
}
```

Using a While or do-while structure is giving me problems, these are the two ways I've used, they create an infinite loop that doesn't increase the variable

```
do {
echo "The number is ".$varIniA."<br/>";
$varIniA+$varIncA;
} 
while ($varIniA <= $varFinA);
```

Using While:

```
while ($varIniA <= $varFinA) {
echo "The number is ".$varIniA."<br />";
$varIniA + $varIncA;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting `$varIniA` in the loops to anything. You're adding a value to essentially nothing causing an infinite loop.

`$varIniA + $varIncA;` should be one of the following:

- `$varIniA ++;`
- `$varIniA = $varIniA + $varIncA;`
- And many more :P